# Nested TreeView with additional properties

Tags: wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

This problem has been solved before, but I'm just not getting it with examples I'm finding online.

I have a class, lets say 'ClassA', this class has 2 string properties, 'Property1' and 'Property2' as well as an IEnumerable where 'ClassB' also has 2 properties. The list of ClassB will all be displayed in a nested treeview

I want these displayed in a treeview like so:

```
-ClassA[0]
  ClassA.Property1
  ClassA.Property2
  -ClassA.ClassB Title
   ClassB[0]
   ClassB[1]
   Etc.
+ClassA[1]
+ClassB[2]
```

It is my understanding that the way to accomplish this is to use HierarchicalDataTemplates however all examples I can find only tell me how to do:

```
-ClassA[0]
  -ClassA.ClassB Title
   ClassB[0]
   ClassB[1]
   Etc.
+ClassA[1]
+ClassB[2]
```

I cant figure out how to get the properties of ClassA in the template. Im thinking it'd be a DataTemplate on type ClassA but something isnt clicking.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I answered my own question, but I dont think it's the right way to go about this.

I used an itemtemplate on the treeview and then created another treeview inside of that template with another itemtemplate on it.

I can however, understand this when I look at it vs looking at the HierarchicalDataTemplates.

WPF:

```
    <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding FileName}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData1}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MetaData2}"/>
                    <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Mappings}" Header="Mappings">
                        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="17"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Original}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="->" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,0,3,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mapping}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Classes:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string MetaData1 { get; set; }
    public string MetaData2 { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> Mappings { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string Original { get; set; }
    public string Mapping { get; set; }
}
```

Quick Implementation of my data structure:

```
new List<ClassA>
                    {
                        new ClassA
                            {
                                FileName = "ClassA 1",
                                MetaData1 = "Prop 1",
                                MetaData2 = "Prop 2",
                                Mappings = new List<ClassB>
                                            {
                                                new ClassB
                                                {
                                                    Original = "BProp 1",
                                                    Mapping = "BProp 2"
                                                }
                                            }
                            },
                        new ClassA
                            {
                                FileName = "ClassA 2",
                                MetaData1 = "Prop 1",
                                MetaData2 = "Prop 2",
                                Mappings = new List<ClassB>
                                            {
                                                new ClassB
                                                {
                                                    Original = "BProp 1",
                                                    Mapping = "BProp 2"
                                                }
                                            }
                            }
                    };
```

If anyone knows how I should have done this better (with HierachicalDataTemplates and DataTemplates Im open to seeing that code and improving upon this.